# What is the opposite of a standfirst?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, terminology, antonyms

A *standfirst* is:

> an introductory paragraph in an article, printed in larger or bolder type or in capitals, which summarizes the article

Collins English Dictionary - Complete & Unabridged 10th Edition. Retrieved December 28, 2017 from Dictionary.com website http://www.dictionary.com/browse/standfirst

What is the opposite of a standfirst — a final paragraph that is distinct from the main body of the article, something that if it were online might be a call to action or in print the address to write a letter to.

Although not a perfect example here is an article from the [Evening Standard](https://www.standard.co.uk/news/london/gregory-tomkins-man-found-dead-on-christmas-morning-after-hanging-himself-live-on-camera-a3727896.html).

[image: A bold final line in an article that is distinct from the body]

Comment: Depends on what you consider the 'opposite'... do you mean, everything that is NOT a standfirst, or a final paragraph printed in smaller type or lowercase, which adds details, or a sidebar, or something else?  There are too many available dimensions for opposition at the moment.

Comment: Can you include an example sentence to express intended usage more clearly. For example when you say opposite to do you mean a concluding paragraph? Printed in smaller type? I guess not... but as you can see your question is somewhat ambiguous at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [**coda**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/coda), perhaps?

> 1.2 A concluding event, remark, or section. (Oxford)